# How to add a Series to a Hierarchical Series

Tags: python, pandas, series, hierarchical

I have a `Hierarchical Series` as below

```
data=pd.Series(np.random.randn(10),
    index=[['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'],
    [1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3]])
```

I would like to insert a new series into `data`

```
t_series = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10))
```

I have tried

```
data['e'] = t_series
```

But failed, could soemone enlighten me how to enlarge a `Hierarchical Series` dynamically?

Comment: Could you explain how you want the resulting Series to look like?

Comment: It will have an additonal first level index named 'e', and a call of `data['e']` will give the the content of `t_series`

Comment: OK, but you also need to specify the second level index.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['e'] = np.random.randn(10)
# or if you already created another series, which perhaps has a different index
df['e'] = t_series.values()
```

*As the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html) note: A [`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#series) is a **one-dimensional** labeled array,  whilst a `DataFrame` is a **2-dimensional** labeled data structure with columns of potentially different types.*

Comment: my Series at the second level doesnt have the same index, so `data['a']` and `data['e']` do not have the same index. In that case I guess i cant use DataFrame?

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the same index? You can force it by using `t_series.values()`.

Comment: Hi, in my original question, `data['e']` is not exist yet, so basically I am trying to assign a Series to that first level index, like a python dictionary. Not sure if that possible though.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want your second level index to be `range(10)`, you may need to do it like this:

```
t_series = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10), index=[('e ' * 10).split(), range(10)])
t_series
```

Then use `concat`:

```
pd.concat([data, t_series])
```